# Find the largest prime number factor?

Tags: c

I need to find
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
/ * Largest is 377. * /
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j = 0;
    /*Code works really fine for 13195 or 26*/
    long value, large = 600851475143 /*13195*/;

    for(value = (large - 1) ; value >= 3; value--)
    {
        if(large % value == 0)
        {
            /*printf("I am here \n");*/
            if((value % 2 != 0) && (value % 3 != 0) && (value % 5 != 0) && (value % 7 != 0) )   
            {
                j = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (j == 1)
    {
        printf("%ld", value);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Where it is going wrong?

Comment: "/ * Largest is 377. * /" Not correct, `377 = 13*29` is not a prime.

Comment: how many bits is long? Your number might be out of range, you need a 64-bit int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
//Euler problem #3
int main(){
    long long i, sqi;
    long long value, large = 600851475143LL;
    long long max = 0LL;

    i   = 2LL;
    sqi = 4LL; //i*i
    for(value = large; sqi <= value ; sqi +=  2LL * i++ + 1LL){
        while(value % i == 0LL){
            value /= (max=i);
        }
    }

    if(value != 1LL && value != large){
        max = value;
    }
    if(max == 0LL){
        max = large;
    }
    printf("%lld\n", max);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I thought those problems were intended to give programmers a thirst of knowledge of math but isn't it a matter of sorrow that some of them are trying to get it around and making it look like a war which can be won by any mean

Answer (score 3):

1. 600851475143 is too big to fit in 32 bit integer. `long` may be 32 bit on your machine. You need to use 64 bit type. The exact data type will be dependent on your platform, compiler.
2. Your prime checking code is wrong. You are assuming that if something is not devided by 2, 3, 5, 7 then that is prime.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing that is wrong here is that your code is too slow: even if you fix other issues, such as using a wrong data type for your integers and trying out some divisors that are definitely not prime, iterating by one down from 10^11 <strike>will simply not finish in your computer's lifetime</strike> is extremely wasteful.

I highly recommend that you [read through the example on page 35 of this classic book](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/ewd02xx/EWD249.PDF), where Dijkstra takes you through the process of writing a program printing the first 1000 prime numbers. This example should provide enough mathematical intuition to you to speed up your own calculations, including the part where you start your search from the square root of the number that you are trying to factor.

Comment: If the computer can do 10^8 divisions per second, going down from 10^11 will take less than 20 minutes, the problem target less than 2 hours. That's one short-lived computer, you should look for a better vendor.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, I thought of the inner loop that tries another `SQRT(10^11)` possibilities (what the OP has as an `if` statement should be a `for` loop going through divisors of the candidate to see if it is prime or not), but since that inner loop will not be entered on the way down to the largest prime divisor, I shouldn't have counted it in my estimates as another 10^5 multiplier. I made a correction to my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

600851475143 is probably above the precision of your platform's `long` data type. It requires at least 40 bits to store. You can use this to figure out how many bits you have:

```
#include <limits.h>

printf("my compiler uses %u bits for the long data type\n", (unsigned int) (CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long)));
```

Comment: -1 but it isn't and even if it was the algorithm isn't right (this code also doesn't work for 72 (highest prime factor is 13 but code will return 26)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `L` as suffix to a number that overflow MAX INT, so this line:

```
long value, large = 600851475143;
```

Should be:

```
long value, large = 600851475143L;
//                              ^
```

Comment: BTW - there might be another problem, but this is the first thing that pops to my eyes.

Comment: -1 this isn't the main problem with the code - it also doesn't work on 72

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to establish that the value is prime - i.e. that is has no prime factors.

Now your little piece of code checking 3/5/7 simply isn't good enough - you need to check is value has ANY lower prime factors (for example 11/13/17).

From a strategic perspective if you want to use this analysis you need to check a list of every prime factor you have found so far and check against them as you are checking against the first 3 primes.

An easier (but less efficient) method would be to write an IsPrimeFunction() and check the primality of the each divisor and store the largest.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LargeFactor{

     public static void main(String []args){
     long num = 600851475143L;
     long largestFact = 0;
     long[] factors = new long[2];

    for (long i = 2; i * i < num; i++) {
         if (num % i == 0) { // It is a divisor
        factors[0] = i;
        factors[1] = num / i;

        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (long j = 2; j * j <  factors[k]; j++) {
                if (factors[k] % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                 }
             }
             if (isPrime && factors[k] > largestFact) {
                largestFact = factors[k];
             }
            }
        }
     }
     System.out.println(largestFact);
}
}
```

Above code utilises the fact that we only need to check all numbers up to the **square root** when looking for factors.