# Determine the largest prime factor

Tags: c, algorithm, prime-factoring

I'm trying to run a brute force algorithm to determine the highest prime factor of a number. Here's my code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



long checkForHighestPrime(long param);

int main(){
    printf("%ld",checkForHighestPrime(600851475143L) );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}


long checkForHighestPrime(long param){

        long d= 0;
        long h = 0;
        long i;

    for (i = 1; i <param; i++){

        //check if it's a factor

        d = param%i;

        // If it's a factor then determine whether its prime

        if(d == 0){

            for(long j = 0; j<i ; j++){
                if (d%j == 0){
                    break;
                }else{
                    h = d;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return h;
}
```

However I end up with the following error

```
Floating point exception: 8
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `if (d == 0) {.... if (d % j == 0) {...} }`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the largest prime number factor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000305/find-the-largest-prime-number-factor)

Answer (score 1):

In your inner `for` loop, you initialize `j` to 0. This causes `d % j == 0` to throw an exception because you are attempting to divide by zero. Also, it appears that `d` should be `i`.

Answer (score 0):

In these 2 lines of code:

```
for(long j = 0; j<i ; j++){
    if (d%j == 0){
```

You try to find d % 0, which is an error. As it is a primality check, you shoud start j at 2.

To increase efficency of your code, I suggest you stop that loop at sqrt(i) instead of i, as every non-prime number has at least one divisor smaller than sqrt(i). Also, as you search for the largest factor, I suggest you start searching backwards from param/2 instead of 1.

Comment: Also, dynamic programming and caching will greatly speed up his routine. In addition, after finding the first factor, it would be much faster to divide the number and check the result. If it is prime, return. Else, factorize iteratively the result.

Answer (score 0):

> Floating point exception: 8

This error from the following code

```
        for(long j = 0; j<i ; j++){
            if (d%j == 0){
```

When `j` is zero, you divide `d` by zero.

By the way, this is a duplication question:

[Find the largest prime number factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000305/find-the-largest-prime-number-factor)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940382/to-calculate-the-prime-factor-of-two-number

and more.