# Returning largest factor of a number is very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x

When substituting `x` in the `get_large` function with a large integer such as 600851475143 the program stalls and doesn't return a value.  But, when substituting `x` with a smaller integer such as 20 it returns the result.  How can I fix this?

```
factors = []  # create new empty list

def calc(x):
    for n in range(1, x):
        if x % n == 0:
            factors.append(n)  # if x is divisible by n append to factor list
    return factors

def get_large(x):
    calc(x)  # call the returned values in factors list
    return calc(x)[-1]  # return the last factor in the list

print("The largest factor is: " + str(get_large(600851475143)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the largest prime number factor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000305/find-the-largest-prime-number-factor)

Comment: **@steven**, Your code is not properly indented. Please indent first so that others will not suggest you to look at your code first. it is `return factors`.

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm using python3

Comment: **steve**, a number is factor of itself, so it will be the largest factor. As I understand, here largest factor actually means second largest factor and its just less than or equal to half of number. In case of `10`, `5` is largest factor. it is just half. Now you can decrease the number of iterations of for loop. You code is ok, but it is taking time to respond. Use `print()` to see, it works.

Comment: Assuming you were trying to solve [Project Euler problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3), you were supposed to find the largest *prime* factor, not just the largest factor.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def get_large(x):
    for n in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))):
        if x % n == 0:
            return x / n
    return 1

print ("The largest factor is: " +str(get_large(600851475143)))
```

Your code is too inefficient and so it takes forever to run for large numbers. The above is a more efficient version.

Comment: The factor we need to return may be greater than any candidate your code tests.

Comment: The original code is incorrect. I have modified the code to the correct one. The answer I get is 8462696833.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not broken, just taking a long time. Python is well known for being slow when running big `for` loops. I would recommend something like the following:

```
def calc(x):
    n = 2
    factors = []
    while x != n:
        if x % n == 0:
            factors.append(n) #if x is divisible by n append to factor list
            x = x / n #this will safely and quickly reduce your big number
            n = 2 #then start back at the smallest potential factor
        else:
            n = n + 1
    return factors #This will return a list of all prime factors

def get_large(x):
    bigFactor = x / calc(x)[0]
    #The largest factor is just the original
    #number divided by its smallest prime factor
    return bigFactor
```

I used 2 as the smallest potential factor because using 1 would get us nowhere :)

Comment: If you replace `if x % n == 0` with `while x % n == 0`, and delete `n = 2`, then you'll save yourself some needless spinning.

Comment: thanks I'll review this more in depth when I get some time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine. Note that `factors` is local to `calc()` so we aren't constantly appending to the previous list.

Also note that `get_large()` only has to call `calc()` once. There is no reason to call it twice.

Finally, I replaced your algorithm in `calc()` with one that should go substantially faster.

```
def calc(x):
    factors = []
    i = 2
    while i < x:
        while x % i == 0:
            x /= i
            factors += [i]
        i += 1
    return factors

def get_large(x):
    return calc(x)[-1] #return the last factor in the list


print ("The largest factor is: " +str(get_large(600851475143)))
```

Result, including timing:

```
$ time python3 x.py
The largest factor is: 1471

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: Oh crud. My program presents the largest *prime* factor, not the largest factor. If you actually want the largest factor, regardless of whether it is prime or composite, don't accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if the number itself is not the largest factor, then why to loop till x, it can looped until x/2 .